# Vite. Place files to separate folders for each entry

Tags: vue.js, build, vite

My project currently uses Vite, Vue3 and TS

I have next project structure
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8Sn7.png)

I want to build and place each index.html file, its style, script and assets to one folder for each input entry

Currently, when I run build with this vite.config

```
build: {
  rollupOptions: {
    input: {
      order: fileURLToPath(
        new URL("./src/views/Order/index.html", import.meta.url)
      ),
      catalog: fileURLToPath(
        new URL("./src/views/Catalog/index.html", import.meta.url)
      ),
      shops: fileURLToPath(
        new URL("./src/views/Shops/index.html", import.meta.url)
      ),
    },
    output: {
      dir: "dist-chunk",
    },
  },
},
```

it places files in dist like this
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7wOt.png)

As you can see, I have separate folders for each entry and index.html inside. But all other related files are placed in assets directory

But I want something like this, when each script and style placed in the same folder with index.html

[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxokC.png)

Does Vite allows such building strategy and how I can configure Vite.config.ts for what I want?

Answer (score 0):

```
rollupOptions: {
        input: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.html'),
        output: {
            assetFileNames: (assetInfo: { name: any }) => {
                let extType = assetInfo.name!.split('.').at(1)
                if (/png|jpe?g|webp/i.test(extType)) {
                    extType = 'img'
                }
                return `assets/${extType}/[name]-[hash][extname]`
            },
            chunkFileNames: 'assets/js/[name]-[hash].js',
            entryFileNames: 'assets/js/[name]-[hash].js',
        },
    },
```

Comment: I recommend that you don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.